# Issue when exporting Google SpreadSheet to XLSX for sending by email

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I have followed some steps  for converting a Spreadsheet to XLSX. But when I try to open the exported and sent file, it says "file or extension not valid". Checking it as an HTML, it says "The file doesn't exist".

If I try the file URL used in the code, directly in browser, it downloads the correct file as XLSX.

Attached you can find a screenshot of the code and a screenshot of the downloaded html.

[HTML result when trying to save spreadsheet in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYU0f.png)

[Implemented code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYDsj.png)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done specifically what you are doing, but I have exported from google docs to other formats.  I always do it by using createFile(blob) after specifying the blob name.  Something like this:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('target folder id');
var doc = 'file name';
var blob = response.getBlob().setName(doc);
var file = folder.createFile(blob);
var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
```

Then include the fileUrl variable in your email.